# Trouble understanding what's wrong with my recursion

Tags: java, recursion

My homework task:

A web developer needs to know how to design a web page's size. So, given a specific rectangular web page’s area, your job by now is to design a rectangular web page, whose length L and width W satisfy the following requirements:

- The area of the rectangular web page you designed must equal to the given target area.
- The width W should not be larger than the length L, which means L >= W.
- The difference between length L and width W should be as small as possible.
- Return an array [L, W] where L and W are the length and width of the web page you designed in sequence.

It says that there is problem in the recursion in the last line and i cannot understand it. Also when i put the code in chatgpt it says that i have to put the L>W condition but i do not see why it is necessary in this code because it can never be bigger than L no ?

```java
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(constructRectangle(20)));
    }

    public static int[] constructRectangle(int a) {
        int L = (int) Math.round(Math.sqrt(a));
        int W = (int) Math.round(Math.sqrt(a));
        return Calcul(a, L, W);
    }

    public static int[] Calcul(int a,int L, int W){
        Math.round(W);
        if (L * W == a ){
            return (new int[]{L,W});
        }
        return (Calcul(a, L + 1, a / L + 1));
    }
}
```

Comment: Why would ChatGPT be able to tell you what to do? It's not a teaching tool, It doesn't know what code is, all it knows is how to write what seems like a convincing story with _zero guarantee_ that the story is actually based on facts. Also, nowhere in the question does it ask you to use recursion, so can you explain why you decided to use recursion to solve this problem?

Comment: i searched up problems on leetcode with the tag recursion and it was up there. I know that it can be solved easily without recursion but i want to train myself to think in a recursive way. Can you maybe recommend me somewhere else where i can train to get better at recursion ? because all of the problems i found can be solved easily wihtout using it and it just complicates it.

Comment: I am guessing that L and W must be integers, but this is nowhere mentioned in your questions. The thing is, if they don't have to be integers, the problem is trivial.

Comment: @AdHass if you want problems that **require recursion**, i know some good ones i enjoyed solving. Try creating an algorithm to **print all the possible combinations of given letters**, **converting numbers to words and vice versa**, also visit **dcoder.com > challenges > hard**

Comment: This problem is not suitable for recursion. You would kill the stack for larger inputs.

Comment: I don't understand the problem. Could you, please, edit the question to show one or more examples?

Comment: @OldDogProgrammer here you go mate https://leetcode.com/problems/construct-the-rectangle/description/
I actually managed to find what was wrong with the code it was just something to do with the parenthesis and in the base condition i missed another condition :). Thank you!

Comment: If you solved your problem, either write up an answer, or if it was "obvious" in retrospect, just delete the question again.

Comment: `Math.round(W);` does nothing.  Also, there is no solution whenever A is a prime number (Other than a 1 pixel wide page of height L).  This is a simple iteration problem, and using recursion is completely inappropriate.  To paraphrase [Jamie Zawinski](http://www.jwz.org/), _"Some people, when confronted with a problem, think_ “I know, I'll use recursion.”  _Now they have two problems."_

Answer (score 0):

In your homework, a = L*W, which means that W = a/L. If you try the next iteration with the next length L+1, it results that the next W should be a/(L+1). The error is that in your code the next W is a / L + 1.

*when i put the code in chatgpt*

If I were you I would not put the code in chatgpt just yet. If this is your homework then your goal is to learn from it. When you are able to verify everything that chatgpt tells you back, then maybe it will be useful to you.
You are correct, W can never be bigger than L. They start from equal values, and then L only increases while W remains the same or decreases.

Comment: Thank you for the response man and for the advice. It is actually not my homework i am just trying to get better at reursion using leetcode haha. The problem with the parethesis you mentioned is what was wrong added to another problem in the base conditino which should be if ((L*W==a)||(L==a) ) instead of just if(L*W==a). Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

**PROBLEM**

The problem with this recursion is that it runs infinitely (never stops) and this causes a **stack overflow error**.

The reason why the error is at line **19**:

```java
return (Calcul(a, L + 1, a / L + 1));
```

is because it's the line that makes the recursive call. (calls `Calcul`)

**WHY IS THE RECURSION RUNNING INFINITELY**

This is because the only condition that terminates the recursion never gets fulfilled.

```java
if (L * W == a )
```

so more calls to `return (Calcul(a, L + 1, a / L + 1));` just continue getting made.

**SOLUTION**

I am not sure if the required values of **L and W** don't need to contain decimals, but I shall use integers like you did.

What we need is to find the multiples of the area with the least difference. For example, when area is `20`. L and W will be `5x4` respectively.

```java
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(getLandW(20)));
    }

    public static int[] getLandW(int area) {
        int LandW[] = new int[2], difference = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

        for (int factor = area, otherFactor, diff; factor > 0; factor--)

            // Stop when we find a factor
            if ((area % factor) == 0) {
                otherFactor = area / factor;
                diff = Math.abs(factor - otherFactor);

                // When the difference of the factors
                // is less than current
                if (diff < difference) {
                    difference = diff;
                    LandW[0] = factor;
                    LandW[1] = otherFactor;
                }
            }

        return LandW;
    }
}
```

This problem did not require recursion to be solved, but if you are up for recursion challenges, here are some.

Make a program to:

1. Print all the possible combinations of letters in a given word.
2. Convert numbers to words [ [My solution](https://github.com/jorexdeveloper/JavaUtils/blob/root/ScientificCalculator/code/jorex/programs/ntw/NumberToWord.java) ].

Find more [here](https://code.dcoder.tech/challenges/).

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I actually managed to find the error. it was as you said a stack overflow and it was because the base condition did not have  another condition with the L*W==a which is (L*W==a)||(a==L) and in the recursion call it needed parenthesis that were not there for the a/(L+1)

Comment: @AdHass You should also know that recursion is more resource intensive and is slower than a loop. Although it may not be significant in small programs, this causes major performance issues in large programs and should be avoided where possible.

Comment: Thank you for the heads up. I know that i can be solved easily iteratively but i am trying to get better at recursion and this was one of the problems witht he recursion tag in leetcode even though it is not the best solution